# How to add others users to my gerrithub.io repositories?

Tags: gerrithub.io

I have imported my private GitHub repos to gerrithub. I want to give review/merge/submit access to another person (Say I know the email of that person). I added public SSH keys under my profile of that person as a result he/she is able to clone my repo with hooks and post the review.

Problem, she/he is not able to view or review his/her changes after posting the review. I tried to read their documents regarding access control but couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add the SSH keys of the other person to your account, otherwise he/she will be able to impersonate your user.

The other person will have to create his/her own account on Gerrithub.io and you will have to grant access to the projects his/her will need to access.

You can set the ACL for your project here: https://review.gerrithub.io/admin/repos/,access